# How do I call functions from a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

Easy one for you guys. Why can't I get cmd to run a function from a dictionary? (I didn't want to paste all the code, but everything called has a class or function somewhere else. I have functions called "help()" and "exit() and such in a commands.py file and it's already been imported.)

The error I'm getting is: "line 87, in runCMD Commands[cmd](Player, args) KeyError: 0"

```
Commands = { #In-game commands
    'help': help,
    'stats': stats,
    'exit': exit
    }

def isValidCMD(cmd):
    if cmd in Commands:
        return True
    return False

def runCMD(cmd, Player, args):
    Commands[cmd](Player, args)

def main(Player): #Main function
    Player.dead = False
    while(Player.dead == False):
        cmd = input(">> ")

        if isValidCMD(cmd):
            runCMD(0, 1, Player)
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid command.")

charactercreation()
main(Player)
```

Comment: What happens when you try this?  Do you get an exception?  If so, print the stack trace so we can help you debug.

Comment: Also, don't you mean to be passing `cmd` to `runCMD`?  Shouldn't that be `runCMD(cmd, Player, 0, 1)`, or something?

Comment: When you call ``runCMD(0, 1, Player)``, ``0`` stands for the ``cmd`` parameter, but there is no such key in ``Commands``. What did you expect that ``0`` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling

```
runCMD(cmd, 1, Player) # or runCMD(cmd, Player, 1) <= looks like they are in the wrong order
```

anyway, they first parameter of `runCMD` needs to be one of the keys in `Commands`

Possibly you mean to pass an arbitrary number of parameters in `args`. then you need to place a `*` in there

```
def runCMD(cmd, Player, *args):
    Commands[cmd](Player, *args)

def main(Player): #Main function
    Player.dead = False
    while(Player.dead == False):
        cmd = input(">> ")

        if isValidCMD(cmd):
            runCMD(cmd, Player, 0, 1)
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid command.")
```

Comment: Ah! That was it! It's always something simple I just happen to overlook. Thank you.

Comment: @DarkWarez: more important than one solution in particular is learning debugging skills.  The simplest is one word: `print`.  `print(obj)`, `print(repr(obj))`, `print(type(obj))`, etc.  Newcomers to SO get some slack, but you'll find that questions will start getting downvoted if you don't show that you've done the work to rule out the obvious.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was mostly just trying hard not to post ALL of my code and take up the whole page in code. Thanks for the tip, though.